# Filtrar filas con un string en cualquier columna de un Data Frame con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtro

Tengo un Data Frame con 14 columnas. Algunas tiene datos de tipo string y otras de tipo int o float.. Necesito poder introducir con un input una consulta, que busque en el `DataFrame` y me devuelva las filas con las coincidencias parciales o totales con cualquier columna. Es decir, si el usuario ingresa 'Carc' que le traiga el juego de 'Name' 'Carcose' y el de 'Name' 'Carcasone' pero a su vez el juego cuyo 'Mechanics' sea 'Carcrow' ...
Idealmente necesitaría hacer una función que recorra todas las columnas y no tener que indicarle cual debe recorrer o si solo debe recorrer las que tienen datos tipo string o tipo int/float.
O sea:

1.Ingreso consulta

2.Retorna filas en cuyas columnas haya encontrado coincidencias totales o parciales.

**Además** debería poder aplicarle varios filtros en simultaneo a una búsqueda.

Soy absolutamente principiante asique seguramente esté faltándome algo esencial para entender lo que quiero hacer.
Dejo algunas pruebas que hice (hice muchas más), aprovechando las consultas en StackOverflow y otro lugares. Me oriente más que nada a la búsqueda `string` porque creo que lo referido a int/float puede llegar a ser más sencillo pero mi objetivo sigue siendo que pueda introducir cualquier consulta y que ingrese siempre a la misma función de filtro.

Dejo una muestra del `DataFrame`:

| ID | Name | Min Players | Max Players | Mechanics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Gloomhaven | 1 | 4 | Action Queue, Action Retrieval, Campaign / Bat... |
| 1 | Pandemic Legacy: Season 1 | 2 | 4 | Action Points, Cooperative Game, Hand Manageme |
| 2 | Brass: Birmingham | 2 | 4 | Hand Management, Income, Loans, Market, Networ... |
| 3 | Terraforming Mars | 1 | 5 | Card Drafting, Drafting, End Game Bonuses, Han... |
| 4 | wilight Imperium: Fourth Edition | 3 | 6 | Action Drafting, Area Majority / Influence, Ar... |

Probé:

```
     if columna in ['Name', 'Mechanics', 'Domains']:
            if df[columna].str.contains(pat = consulta) == True:
                print('Anduvo.')
            else:
                print('No anduvo.')
    
#Me devuelve
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Donde consulta es el input y columna es un valor de una lista de columnas del `DataFrame`. En el if chequee que el valor columna sea de una columna con datos string. (No es exactamente lo que quiero pero para ver si lograba algo)

Probe también:

```
        consulta = [consulta]
        if columna in ['Name', 'Mechanics', 'Domains']:    
            resultado = df[df[columna].isin(consulta)]
            print(resultado)
        else:
            print('No anduvo')
#Me devuelve    
Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [ID, Name, Year Published, Min Players, Max Players, Play Time, Min Age, Users Rated, Rating Average, BGG Rank, Complexity Average, Owned Users, Mechanics, Domains]
    Index: []
```

Probe:

```
resultado = df[~df['Name'].isin([consulta])]
print(resultado)
# Me filtra bien pero, obviamente, sólo por la columna indicada
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega las filas del `dataframe` como texto, no como imagen para que podamos utilizarlas.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, ahi lo modifique. Espero que ahora sí sea correcto el formato. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Cree un `dataframe` genérico de la siguiente forma:

```
    id  col1    col2
0   1   abc     cda
1   2   def     fgabc
2   3   hij     a1dsf5
3   4   klm     bcf
```

### Método 1

Utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) puedes buscar algún `string` en todo el `dataframe` de la siguiente forma:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('bc').any(), axis=1)
```

Esto devolvería `True` si el `string` aparece en cualquier columna y `False` si no, buscando el `string` "bc" en el `dataframe` de ejemplo obtenemos:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

La línea anterior la podemos utilizar como filtro para que nos devuelva las filas que contienen el `string` que buscamos

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('bc').any(), axis=1)]
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    id  col1    col2
0   1   abc     cda
1   2   def     fgabc
3   4   klm     bcf
```

### Método 2

Utilizando [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) podemos buscar en todas las columnas algún `string` de la siguiente forma

```
np.column_stack([df[col].astype(str).str.contains("bc", na=False) for col in df])
```

Esto devuelve un arreglo donde muestra si alguna "celda" contiene el `string` que se busca

```
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True]])
```

La línea anterior la podemos utilizar como filtro para el `dataframe` y luego podemos seleccionar las filas de la siguiente forma:

```
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].astype(str).str.contains("bc", na=False) for col in df])
df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    id  col1    col2
0   1   abc     cda
1   2   def     fgabc
3   4   klm     bcf
```

### Diferencia de tiempo de ejecución

Al hacer mediciones del tiempo de ejecución el segundo método es más rápido:

En este `dataframe` tan pequeño el primer método se ejecutó en

```
--- 0.0020096302032470703 seconds ---
```

Y el segundo método en

```
--- 0.0010089874267578125 seconds ---
```

Comment: ambos métodos funcionaron perfectamente y tal como decis, el segundo método es mucho mas rápido. Sin embargo, intento hacer una función con esto que me propones y me da:

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'any'. Tenes idea como puedo sortear eso?